# Сравнение введённого значения с null с помощью тернарного оператора

Tags: javascript

```
var askName = prompt("What is your name?", '');

if (askName == "hovo") {
  var askPasswd = prompt("Type password", ''); 
  if (askPasswd == "shax") {
    alert("Hello Admin");
  }
  else if (askPasswd == null) {
    alert("Escape of password");
  }
  else {
    alert("Wrong Password");
  }
}
else if (askName == null) {
  alert("Escape of name");
}
else {
  alert("I don't know You");            
}
```

Вышеописанный код захотел переписать тернарным оператором:

```
var askName = prompt("What is Your Name?", '');
var askPasswd;  
(askName == null) ? alert("Escape from name") :                     
  (askName != "hovo") ? alert("I don't know you") :
    (askPasswd = prompt("Type your login", '') == "shax") ? alert("Hello Admin") :
      (askPasswd == null) ? alert("Escape from password") : alert("Wrong Password");
```

Но "барахлит" `askPasswd == null`: отвечает "Wrong Password".

В чем проблема? Как по-другому можно было написать с помощью тернарного оператора?

Comment: null - тип переменной, попробуй сравнение по типу: (askPasswd === null)

Comment: Увы, не сработало, к тому сверху сработало нестрогое равенство...

Comment: Если `askPasswd == null` выдаёт `false`, то `askPasswd === null` уж тем более выдаст тот же `false`. Ну и `null` - это не тип переменной.

Comment: null это тип данных..

Comment: @HovhannesShaxulyan нет, это не тип данных. Это значение. Вкратце прочитать про него можно, например, [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null).

Comment: @Regent, null считается и типом данных и значением.

Comment: @HovhannesShaxulyan, впрочем, твоё сообщение ответом, очевидно, не является.

Comment: @Qwertiy всё же `null` - это значение (чаще всего имеют в виду как раз его, и именно его использовал Zhooravlik для сравнения со значением `askPasswd`), а тип - `Null` (единственным значением которого является `null`, да). Я отталкиваюсь от спецификации ECMAScript 2015. Если с тех пор что-то поменялось - было бы здорово об этом узнать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В строке

```
(askPasswd = prompt("Type your login", '') == "shax")
```

в `askPasswd` присваивается результат сравнения введённого значения и строки "shax", то есть либо `true`, либо `false`.
В случае `true` выводится `alert` с текстом "Hello Admin", в случае `false` - идёт сравнение с `null`, которое даёт `false` (потому что `false != null`).

Что в итоге надо сделать:

```
((askPasswd = prompt("Type your login", '')) == "shax")
```

---

А ещё итоговый код тяжело читать. Если очень хочется уменьшить количество `if-else`-ов в пользу тернарного оператора, то стоит это делать только там, где это не ухудшит читаемость кода. Переписать код можно, например, так:

```js
var name = prompt("What is Your Name?", '');
if (name == "hovo") {
  var password = prompt("Type password", '');
  if (password == "shax")
    alert("Hello admin");
  else
    alert(password == null ? "Escape of password" : "Wrong password");
}
else {
  alert(name == null ? "Escape from name" : "I don't know you");
}
```

Comment: Получилось, спасибо, А ведь знаете, я так и  задумывал сначала, что весь промпт  надо заключить в скобки, потом проверил, что итак работает хелло админ, не поставил скобки, в результате чего появились нежелательные последствия...

Comment: @HovhannesShaxulyan на здоровье. Я добавил в конец ответа вариант "от себя", ибо читать код из кучи тернарных операторов очень тяжело, да и легко ошибиться при их написании.

Answer (score 1):

```
askPasswd = prompt("Type your login", '') == "shax"
```

что после этого в `askPasswd`? Может ли там быть `null`?

```
console.log(false == null) // что выведет?
```

Comment: @HovhannesShaxulyan - ответ Regent-a лучше